# libexpat1-dev and libgtk2.0-dev (No package 'gtk+-2.0' found)

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, 20.04, gtk

I am trying to install `lablgtk` via the following:

`opam install lablgtk`

It gives me following error:

```
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build lablgtk 2.18.11
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed

<><> lablgtk.2.18.11 troubleshooting ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
=> This package requires gtk+ 2.0 development packages installed on your system

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please
make sure they are installed before retrying:
    libexpat1-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

I tried this:
`sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev`
but it says that
`libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.32-1ubuntu1).`

Also similar thing happens for:
`sudo apt-get install -y libexpat1-dev` where I get `libexpat1-dev is already the newest version (2.2.5-3ubuntu0.2).`

I tried both on *Ubuntu 18.04LTS and 20.04LTS*. Any suggestion what could be the solution?

Complete output:

```
  ∗ install lablgtk 2.18.11

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[lablgtk.2.18.11] found in cache

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] The compilation of lablgtk failed at
        "/home/user/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ./configure
        --prefix /home/user/.opam/default
        LABLGLDIR=/home/user/.opam/default/lib/lablgl".

#=== ERROR while compiling lablgtk.2.18.11 ====================================#
# context     2.0.7 | linux/x86_64 |  | https://opam.ocaml.org#87778c51
# path        ~/.opam/default/.opam-switch/build/lablgtk.2.18.11
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ./configure --prefix /home/user/.opam/default LABLGLDIR=/home/user/.opam/default/lib/lablgl
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/lablgtk-32104-d0f245.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/lablgtk-32104-d0f245.out
### output ###
# [...]
# checking whether C compiler accepts -fno-unwind-tables... yes
# checking platform... Unix
# checking native dynlink... checking for pkg-config... /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pkg-config
# checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.0.0... Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
# Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
# to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
# No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
# no
# *** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
# *** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
# *** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
# configure: error: GTK+ is required



<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build lablgtk 2.18.11
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed

<><> lablgtk.2.18.11 troubleshooting ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
=> This package requires gtk+ 2.0 development packages installed on your system

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please
make sure they are installed before retrying:
    libexpat1-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

`which opam` gives `/usr/local/bin/opam` and `which ocaml` gives `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ocaml`

Comment: What was wrong with installing deb-packaged [version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/lablgtk2) by `sudo apt-get install liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev` ?

Comment: That finishes successfully but still I get the same error when I run `opam install proverif` where lablgtk is one of the dependencies. Actually I am installing ProVerif (Section 1.4.1 in https://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/proverif/manual.pdf) Maybe I need to somehow set the path where opam should look for, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please add output of `which opam` and `which ocaml` to the question body. Why do you have mentions of `linuxbrew` in output above?

Comment: `which opam` gives `/usr/local/bin/opam` and `which ocaml` gives `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ocaml`

Comment: I would recommend to remove ocaml, which was installed by linuxbrew. And then retry method from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing that you are using LinuxBrew to install stuff on Ubuntu.
It may be good for other stuff, but in the current case it leads to unpredictable and non-reproducible results.

So I would recommend to remove OPAM and OCaML which where installed using LinuxBrew and then install all the stuff using deb-packages from official repositories.

```
brew uninstall ocaml-findlib
brew uninstall ocaml
brew uninstall opam
brew uninstall gcc
brew uninstall gcc@5

rm -rf ~/.opam
sudo rm -v /usr/local/bin/opam
```

Then to install ProVerif we can follow [PKGBUILD from ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=proverif).

```
sudo apt install -y graphviz ocaml-nox liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/proverif/proverif2.02pl1.tar.gz
tar -xf proverif2.02pl1.tar.gz
cd proverif2.02pl1/
./build

# optionally run tests
#./test all
#./test-type all

# and install binaries
sudo install -Dm755 proverif /usr/local/bin/proverif
sudo install -Dm755 proveriftotex /usr/local/bin/proveriftotex
sudo install -Dm755 proverif_interact /usr/local/bin/proverif_interact
```

And then call the executables from anywhere as `proverif`, `proveriftotex` or `proverif_interact`.

Comment: `./build` gives this now: `ocamlfind: Package lablgtk2 not found`

Comment: You have to restore default ocaml configuration. The answer above uses only deb-packages.

Comment: I am new to ocaml. Can you update the answer with that?

Comment: Start with `rm -rf ~/.opam`

Comment: Still it gives the following error ```File "display_interact.ml", line 1:
Error: /usr/lib/ocaml/lablgtk2/gMain.cmi
       is not a compiled interface for this version of OCaml.
It seems to be for an older version of OCaml.
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I confirm that it works. Please update the 3 occurrences of `proverif2.01` to `proverif2.02pl1` which is the latest version (and I tested this) so that I accept your answer.

Comment: Done search and replace. Great!